# magento coupon code for free shipping

Tags: php, magento

I need to generate coupon code which allow customer "Free Shipping". I have generated one with following options:

Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules

- All Customer Groups
- Specific Coupon
- Coupon Code
- no condition
- Free Shipping - For matching items only

I am getting all shipping methods with price `$0` where I want `Free Shipping` option included with all shipping method with their actual price. There is setting in *System -> Configuration*, free shipping is available for `price > 100`, but I want to give `free shipping` option to some customers using coupon. I am getting following options:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should try event observer which check the specified coupon code and then set shipping as free shipping.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way Magento rules generally work.

To implement this change, you need to either write your own extension or get a ready-to-use solution.

E.g. our Magento shipping extension is capable of doing that: http://www.mageworx.com/shipping-suite-magento-extension.html